# Next.js and redux. Populating store on server side does not take effect

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, next.js

I connected redux to Next.js app just [like in the docs](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/with-redux) (not sure what [mapDispatchToProps](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/master/examples/with-redux/pages/index.js#L30) does in the example though):

**Init store method:**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
import axios from 'axios';
import axiosMiddleware from 'redux-axios-middleware';
import tokenMiddleware from './tokenMiddleware';
import getReducer from './combineReducers';

const logger = createLogger({ collapsed: true, diff: true });
const axiosMw = axiosMiddleware(axios.create(), { successSuffix: '_SUCCESS', errorSuffix: '_FAILURE' });

export default function initStore(logActions) {
  return function init() {
    const middleware = [tokenMiddleware, axiosMw];
    if (logActions) middleware.push(logger);
    return createStore(getReducer(), applyMiddleware(...middleware));
  };
}
```

**HOC which I use to connect pages:**

```
import 'isomorphic-fetch';
import React from 'react';
import withRedux from 'next-redux-wrapper';
import { setUser } from 'lib/publisher/redux/actions/userActions';
import PublisherApp from './PublisherApp';
import initStore from '../redux/initStore';

export default Component => withRedux(initStore(), state => ({ state }))(
  class extends React.Component {
    static async getInitialProps({ store, isServer, req }) {
      const cookies = req ? req.cookies : null;
      if (cookies && cookies.user) {
        store.dispatch(setUser(cookies.user));
      }

      return { isServer };
    }

    render() {
      console.log(this.props.state);
      return (
        <PublisherApp {...this.props}>
          <Component {...this.props} />
        </PublisherApp>
      );
    }
  }
);
```

The problem I'm having is that dispatched action

```
store.dispatch(setUser(cookies.user));
```

seems to work fine on server (I've debugged reducer and I know this user object from cookies is indeed handled by reducer) but when I do `console.log(this.props.state)` I get reducer with initial state - without user data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing second parameter inside createStore call. Try this:

```
export default function initStore(logActions) {
  return function init(initData) {
    const middleware = [tokenMiddleware, axiosMw];
    if (logActions) middleware.push(logger);
    return createStore(getReducer(), initData, applyMiddleware(...middleware));
  };
}
```

Notice added initData parameter and it's usage.

Comment: yeah it works! but the parameter should go to inner function.